# c# break while and foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, while-loop

I have a little difficulty solving a problem. I'm looking for all the elements that take a class called '_1VfKB'. Inside this element at a span with a 'data-icon' as an attribute. I am using the while loop so if the data-icon receives a value X it keeps running, otherwise it ends the loop (while). However, how can I break the while when my condition is triggered?

```
private void CheckIfMsgSent() {
  while (true) {
   IReadOnlyCollection < IWebElement > els = driver.FindElementsByClassName("_1VfKB");
   foreach(IWebElement el in els) {
     IWebElement span = el.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));

     if (span.GetAttribute("data-icon") == "status-time") {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      break;
     }
     /* If no element is found with the data-icon = "status-time", break while and break foreach*/

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Set a condition other than `true`.

Comment: Why Sleep() inside a search method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some languages like PHP, you can do `break 2` to break out of two loops...but in C#, and really for clarity of code, you're better off to make your code more readable.  E.g. add a "continueLooking" variable.

The logic explained for how you break out twice was confusing because you put the comment INSIDE the loop.  The only way this makes sense to me is for it to be outside the loop...otherwise you're existing the loop on the first iteration every time...so with the best understanding of the code I can muster, I think it should look something like this:

```
private void CheckIfMsgSent() {
  var continueLooking = true;
  bool foundElement;

  while (continueLooking) {
   foundElement    = false;
   IReadOnlyCollection < IWebElement > els = driver.FindElementsByClassName("_1VfKB");
   foreach(IWebElement el in els) {
     IWebElement span = el.FindElement(By.TagName("span"));

     if (span.GetAttribute("data-icon") == "status-time") {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      foundElement = true;
      break;
     }
   }
   if( !foundElement ) {
     continueLooking = false;
   } 
 }
```

Comment: This logic is counter to what he states in his comment.  You are breaking the inner and outer loops on success in finding a data-icon with value status-time.  His comment states if None are found, break out.

Comment: @user7396598, yeah, I'm trying to make sense of that...it looks like he breaks the first loop on the first iteration EVERY time and breaks the while() whenever the element is not found...doesn't appear to make much sense to me.

Comment: Me neither, lol.  His two conditions seems to conflict each other.

Comment: @KrolNoir, I did one more edit a minute ago...not sure if you tested before or after that...but I was only defining `foundElement` outside the `while`...so if I understand, `foundElement` needs to be set to false on EACH iteration or after it finds an element the first time, it may stay true forever.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable before the start of the while, then within it, where you have your comments, change the state of that variable.

begin with:

```
bool loopState = true;
while(loopState)
{
    bool found = false;
    if (span.GetAttribute("data-icon") == "status-time") {
        found = true;          
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        break;
    }
```

Then where you have this comment:

```
/* If no element is found with the data-icon = "status-time", break while and break foreach*/
```

Add this:

```
if(!found)
    loopState = false;
```

This breaks the inner loop on success, but keeps the outer loop operating.  If however you hit all elements and do not match, the next iteration of your While loop will not execute, and thus your Foreach will not execute either.